# applying different delay for similar elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, delay

I have something like this:

```
    <div class="pictures">
            <img src="01.jpg" id="b1"/>
            <img src="02.jpg" id="b2" />
            <img src="03.jpg" id="b3" />
            <img src="04.jpg" id="b4" />
    </div>
```

And I want each of images to appear, one after another one with some delay. I have written this code, but it's not a perfect solution, because I would need to set a specific id for each of elements which I want to avoid. The script is here:

```
  $('#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4').hide();

      setTimeout(function() {
       $('#b1').fadeIn(500)
      }, 600);

      setTimeout(function() {
       $('#b2').fadeIn(500)
      }, 700);

      setTimeout(function() {
       $('#b3').fadeIn(500)
      }, 800);

      setTimeout(function() {
       $('#b4').fadeIn(500)
      }, 900);

});
```

What ideally would work is a script which applies to every 'img' inside div with a class '.pictures' some delay let's say 100ms higher than the previous 'img' (starting from 600 for example). The fadeIn is constant (500). I tried javascript and function 'for' but didn't manage to do this. 
so I want the first img to fadeIn (500) after 600 ms, the second to fadein (500) with 700 delay, the next one 800ms delay etc...

I will keep adding new images in time, but I don't want to change the script, so the automation of it is necessary. Thank you for all sugestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I've figured it out. this will work:

```
$('.pictures img').hide().each(function(i){
  (function(e, i){
    setTimeout(function() {
       e.fadeIn(500);
    }, 500+100*i); 
  })($(this), i);
});
```

thanks for all suggestions

Comment: I found this and modified in another answer I found on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that like this:

```
delay = 0;
$('.pictures img').each(function () {
    $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn();
    delay += 100;
});
```

What that does is it delays the fadeIn for each img inside the div with class pictures.

Comment: what I really want to do is to display them one after another with delay.

Comment: sorry my mistake. I've updated the answer. It's a nice, clean and easy method to do what you want.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski but apparently it is slower than the method you found (http://jsperf.com/fade-images-sequentially-jquery), so I guess you should use the one you have, not this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use each.

```
 $('#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4').hide();
 $('#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4').each(function(){
      starter = 400;
      current = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
       current.fadeIn(500)
      }, starter = 100);
 });
```